# What is time complexity of fun()?

Tags: c, runtime

what is run time in function exe:log(n)

```
int fun(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            count += 1;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Is O(log n) your guess? Why do you think that?

Comment: A _very smart_ compiler would makes this `O(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not O(log n), but it is O(n). You can think about it like this: Each run of the outer loop sends the remaining data (originally `n`) into the inner loop for processing, and then removes one half of it. The inner loop is clearly linear in the data it processes.

At first iteration, the outer loop sends the whole `n` into the inner loop, which "pays" `n` steps for processing it.

At the second iteration, there is `n / 2` data left, so the innter loop pays `n / 2` for it; it has payed `1.5n` in total.

At the next iteration, there is `n / 2 / 2 == n/4` data left, for which the inner loop pays an extra `n/4`, so `1.75n` in total.

And so on, until the entire `n` has been paid for twice, so the cost is `2n`, which is O(n), actually even ϴ(n).

Comment: I agree about the result, but the number of steps is actually closer to `n * 2` than `n`.

Comment: I agree with everything except the *initial* outer loop, which doesn't "discard" *anything*. Therefore, the inner loop is O(n) right out of the gate. Everything else is piled on to that, Overall, it's accurate to be O(n) regardless.

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that this reasoning assumes a uniform cost model. When using a logarithmic cost model, the time complexity is higher (i.e. on mcu's without barrel shifter or the like).

Comment: @Ctx: it does not take a barrel shifter to implement `i / 2` in constant time especially when `i` is known to be positive, a single shifter suffices. A barrel shifter is required for shifting by n places in a single clock. A processor that does not support single shifting would be very crippled indeed.

Comment: @chqrlie This was merely an example where many operations can not be assumed to be performed in constant time. Another example would be an arbitrary precision library and large numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity would be

> O(n)

For example suppose we take n=32
so for various iterations the number of times loop will run is
32,16,8,4,2,1

So on adding it will be 63 which is the total number of times loop ran
and that is **2*n-1**

Mathematically ,for any value which it is a G.P Sum where the series is like n,n/2,n/4,n/8......1

suppose we take n=32 again
then

sum = a * (1-r^nof)/(1-r) = 32 * (1-(1/2)^5)/(1-(1/2)) = 63

where nof(number of times outer loop ran)=5 is log2n, a=32, r=(1/2)

> for any number it will be less than 2*n

Answer (score 0):

The Time Complexity of your code is **O(n)** only.